# how to capture the current domain name in a URL using flask python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I want to capture a domain name dynamically from any websites using python.

```
 Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
expected output: stackoverflow.com
```

Here everything should be dynamic, Dynamic URL, Dynamic Domain Name.

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend using [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse).

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
o = urlparse('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')
base_url = f'{o.scheme}://{o.hostname}'
# or just the hostname, which is what you probably want
hostname = o.hostname
```

Edit:
Just in case I'm misunderstanding you, here's a function that would return the hostname for every url you enter:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def get_hostname(url):
    return urlparse.host(url)
```

Comment: but  I want the URL should be dynamic how can I capture the URL dynamically

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Considering you can enter the url as a variable into the function, it already is dynamic.